# Filter bind source

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I have a bind source which is filled with following data

```
TOM JACK
JACK TOM
TOM DEISE
JACK JENNY
TOM DALTON
JERRY JOY
JOY JERRY
```

And I have a combobox which is also filled with the above data, For example If i choose `JACK TOM` then the boind source should filter the result so that I need to get the following result

result :

```
TOM JACK
JACK TOM
```

(Only wanted to show the name that contains both the WORD('TOM' and 'JACK') only)

following is my try

```
bndSourceGrid.Filter = String.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", "Name", cboName.Text)
bndSourceGrid.Sort = "Name ASC"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build your query to look like this:

```
Name LIKE '%tom%' AND Name LIKE '%jack%' ....
```

So take your input, split it up, project it to a new string and join them all together with `AND`:

```
bndSourceGrid.Filter = 
    string.Join(" AND ",
        cboName.Text
        .Split(' ')
        .Select(s => string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", s))
    );
```

As noted in the comments, you may need to return the results of the `Select` as an array:

```
bndSourceGrid.Filter = 
    string.Join(" AND ",
        cboName.Text
        .Split(' ')
        .Select(s => string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", s))
        .ToArray()
    );
```

Comment: getting this error `Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectArrayIterator2[System.String,System.String]' to type 'System.String[]'.`

Comment: FYI, I converted the code to vb.net to work in my environment i.e `bndSourceGrid.Filter = String.Join(" AND ", cboName.Text.Split(" "C).[Select](Function(s) String.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", s)))`

Comment: Why didn't you tag your question with `VB.Net` instead of `C#` then? I have no clue how VB.Net uses Linq. Not sure why you get the error, perhaps you can append `.ToArray()` after the `Select`?